# help with jquery jQuery.validator.addMethod

Tags: jquery, validation

http://jsfiddle.net/nBuut/

I am trying to validate the amount fields if only the question above has a value of "yes". Say, you pick yes for question 1, it will ask for a valid number as an amount for question number1.

However, if I select no for the rest of the questions, the form won't submit because it's still asking for valid amounts for question number 2 thru number 5.

Is there a way to do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: The fiddle seems to work for me once I added a reference to the validate js file. http://jsfiddle.net/nBuut/3/

Comment: @BNL try changing question #2 from no to yes. you will see the "valid number req" message again. i need this to not run if the answer is no.

Comment: As long as I enter 'No' in the boxes, it validates. Are you saying there should be some dependency between the questions? I guess I still don't understand.

Comment: @BNL Sorry for the confusion. There is dependency between the amount and the question. If question is answered as yes, then the amount should be validated. If the question is answered no, then the user is not supposed to enter an amount.

Comment: I see now, I didn't realize it wasn't sumitting when the boxes all said "Ok!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
  answerYesNo_1: { required:true } ,

  answerYesNoText_1: { required: function(element) { 
             return $('#answerYesNo_1').val() == 'yes';
  }, number: true },
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the dependency for the input field to the dropdown.

Instead of hardcoding answerYesNoText_1 to true

```
answerYesNoText_1: { required:true, amtGreaterThanZero:true  }
```

You would need something with dependancy check (Not tested code) -

```
answerYesNoText_1: { required: function(element) {
    if ( $('#answerYesNo_1').val() == 'Yes' ) {
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

This would check the amount field only if the dropdown is marked to yes

More @ http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required